# Implementing an application-wide cache in android

Tags: java, android, caching

I am using an extension of an [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) to store the results of network calls. Currently the cache is an instance variable in a fragment (the only place it is needed), and is recreated every time the app is rotated or paused.  How can I make the cache persist through rotations and pausing/resuming the app?

I read that I could use [setRetainInstanceState to handle the rotation case](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html), but this both doesn't help with the pausing and resuming case and would require me to not add the fragment to the backstack.

I could also [extend Application](http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/126377651/global-application-state-in-android), but it seems a little non-encapsulated give that the cache is only needed in one fragment.

Would putting the cache in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) be a good approach?  It's not clear to me how the service would interact with the fragment, but it looks like I could bind the service to the app so it would terminate only when the app did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do such things in the Application object itself...

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

private LruCache cache; // or whatever

public Thing getThingFromCache(String key) { /* or whatever */ }

}
```

... don't forget to put MyApplication in the Manifest ...

```
<application
   android:name=".MyApplication"
   android:icon="@drawable/icon"
   android:label="@string/name"
   >

   <!-- whatever -->

</application>
```

Also, consider using [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), a networking library by Google.

Comment: I was hesitant to use this method because it seemed like excessive global state.  Do you know if this is considered standard?

Comment: It is acceptable, if not a standard approach. Just remember to @Override Application's onLowMemory() to clear your cache. The alternatives are writing your cache to disk (disk files, SQLite, etc), which will work, or subclassing Service ... but why introduce another Context?